# Issues in Webservice

Tags: java, android, web-services

My issue is if I am entering username,password,email register failure toast message appeared.can any one solve this problem in back ground task class and main activity ?

please can any one make it into it appears like register success?

```
 public void submitDetails(View v) 

{




        String username = et.getText().toString();
        String password = et1.getText().toString();
        String email = et2.getText().toString();

        String emailpatern = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
        if (username.equals("")) {
            et.setError("pls enter name");
        } else if (password.equals("")) {
            et1.setError("pls enter last name");
        } else if (email.equals("")) {
            et2.setError("Pls Enter Valid Email");
        } else if (!email.matches(emailpatern)) {
            et2.setError("Pls Enter Valid email charcters");
        }
        BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask();
        backgroundTask.execute(username,password,email);

    }
    class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {
        String reg_url;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            reg_url ="http://iwt.devxenorix.com/webservices/create-user.php";
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args)
        {
            String username,password,email;
            username = args[0];
            password = args[1];
            email = args[2];
            try {
                URL ur = new URL(reg_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ur.openConnection();
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter  = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
                String register = URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(register);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return "Registered...";
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "register failure";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please check if your response is correct or nor in postman or hurlit.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending data for POST request.So for the request you must send the parameters.First in your postman check if the response for the url is correct or not,after that integrate it in your code:

Your do in Background method should be like this:

```
 @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... args)
            {
URL ur = new URL(reg_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ur.openConnection();
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name, "Anil Kumar John"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "anil123"));
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "anil@gmail.com"));
    }
```

Comment: Could  u write with http url connection @crazyandroid

Comment: Didn't got you@Anil Kumar John,You want the url for registration?

Comment: You can get the url from the backend programmer.Or else if you are facing problems use this  https://www.mockable.io/ to create mockable webservice.

Comment: i dont know but it show as registration failure@Crazy android

Comment: Don't worry @Anil Please check your URL properly in postman or hurlit.You can easily get the response.

Comment: Service url is correct  i am using to connect with using phpscript and mysql database but it cant get @crazy Android

Comment: HttpClient and Http Post all are depricated methods then y we are using here

Comment: Depreciated method never indicates that you can't use it,Instead replacements for them are available in developers.android.com@AnilKumarJohn

Comment: but in android studio there is no httpcliennt and httppost  methods and classes

Comment: Yes that's why we use Gson library@AnilLumarJohn